# Add FlutterBlue plugin in offline mode

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, offline, flutter-dependencies

I am attempting to add flutter blue in as a dependency into my app in offline mode.

I cannot run the pub get method as it times out. I believe this is due to me operating behind a proxy server. I've already added the server's certificate into android studio. I know that it recognizes the certificate because I can create and run a basic android app project. However, for some reason flutter's communication is still being blocked.

As I work from a desktop computer, I cannot simply move my computer temporarily to an open network to do the pub get methods.

Is there a way I can install the flutter blue package in offline mode? Or is there a way to get flutter to properly connect to the internet behind a proxy server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do a time consuming hack to add the flutterBlue package into my SDK behind my proxy server. To do this I downloaded the flutterBlue package from [publink](https://pub.dev/flutter)
and extracted it into a new folder called flutter_blue I created in the flutter/packages/ directory of my sdk.

I then opened the pubspec.yaml for flutterBlue and checked its dependencies. Since flutterBlue also required its own dependencies, I had to download and add those into my SDK as well. After each addition, I commented out the dependency value in the pubspec.yaml file. This is because it was now included in the flutter SDK. I repeated this process with the other new additions until no new packages were required.

Below is an example of the updated dependencies section for the flutterBlue package's pubspec.yaml file after I had added its dependencies into the SDK.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  #convert: '^2.1.1'
  #protobuf: '^0.13.12'
  #rxdart: '^0.22.0'
```

After completing the SDK set-up, I then went into my project and opened the .packages file and added the paths to the library folder I had added. Below is what packages I had to include to get flutterBlue support:

```
convert:file:///<Hard path location of flutter SDK folder>/flutter/packages/convert/lib
rxdart:file:///<Hard path location of flutter SDK folder>/flutter/packages/rxdart/lib
protobuf:file:///<Hard path location of flutter SDK folder>/flutter/packages/protobuf-0.13.12/lib
fixnum:file:///<Hard path location of flutter SDK folder>/flutter/packages/fixnum/lib
flutter_blue:file:///<Hard path location of flutter SDK folder>/flutter/packages/flutter_blue/lib/
```

The downside of doing it this way is that whenever you create a new flutter project (in offline mode of course) you will have to edit the .packages file to include the packages you manually added as they are not included through the auto-generation process.

If you want to update the packages you need to get you newest release and replace the contents manually with the updated package and verify you have all of its dependencies commented out and included within the SDK Package.

Comment: I've discovered this method is also annoying when sharing the project through git. The SDK location is different for each computer and because of this, any different computer needs to use its own unique .packages file. Therefore, the set-up is a hassle for teammates as its not a simple download the repo and you can start. If someone adds a package to the SDK then everyone needs to manually add it to their .packages file you cannot use the commit someone else did.